AjaxQ jQuery plugin always undefined
I'm trying to use the AjaxQ plugin with jQuery to queue some ajax requests but seems to be just undefined whatever I try.
Getting the following error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isRunning')

jsfiddle Demo
The code is super simple, the AjaxQ library is included, and I'm just doing this console log as an initial step to see if the library is working properly, before even writing any other code:
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log($.ajaxq.isRunning('Test'));
});

What am I missing here?

Error in the console: "The resource from “https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Foliotek/AjaxQ/v0.0.2/ajaxq.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/plain”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)"

That error is because you're leeching the content from Github. It's not a CDN. Host the file yourself, or use a legit CDN URL

Ah! This makes sense - where are you seeing that error though? I'm looking in the Chrome Dev Console and can't see that anywhere?

Just checked in Firefox and I see this warning there. Massive help, thanks @VLAZ and Rory.

This was caused by linking directly to the file in Github, so file inclusion was being blocked! Chrome didn't show that this was happening very clearly in DevTools, but comments pointed out an error message in Firefox Dev Tools.
Once I included this file locally it all started working as expected.
